# How can I cover spaces in html and css?

Tags: html, css

[image]

```css
.container {
  width: 40%;
  background-color: gray;
}

.skills {
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  color: #5cdb95;
}

.py {
  width: 60%;
  background-color: #05386b;
}

.cpp {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: #05386b;
}

.word {
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #05386b;
}

.exp-main {
  font-size: 26px;
  margin-left: 8em;
}
```

```html
<div class="exp-main">
  <div class="poz-ayar">
    <p>Python</p>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="skills py"></div>
    </div>
    <p>C++</p>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="skills cpp"></div>
    </div>
    <p>Word&Excel</p>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="skills word"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

What I want to do is cover the left and upper blanks but somehow I can't do it, what's wrong with it?

Comment: "*I want to...cover the left and upper blanks*" - what "left and upper blanks"? Where are they? What are they? Do you mean the margin on the left hand side that's moving the content away from the left edge of the screen? Or away from the start of the screen?

Comment: left and upper of red background

Comment: So the white space in the image you posted? It's worth pointing out that the code you provided - that I turned into a runnable snippet - in your question doesn't reproduce the issue, as there's no 'red background'. Can you update the snippet to reproduce the behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the full code, I would guess that there’s a margin within the red element that is “escaping” out and pushing the element away from those around it.

You would need to inspect the DOM in the browser to see where the margin is coming from.

Take a look at Block Formatting Context to understand why those margins are not being contained:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context